# View row does not reflect correct value

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to display a list of items, each item having an index and a visibility flag.  When I change the visibility of the item, and then move it down the list, the visibility of the item is not correctly reflected in the list.

To reproduce the issue 1) add 3 items by tapping on the `+` button, 2) change visibility of `PLOT 1` by tapping on the `eye` icon, 3) tap the down icon on `PLOT 1` swapping it with `PLOT 2`.  I am expecting that `PLOT 1` will have visibility false and `PLOT 2` will have visibility true, but instead they are reversed: `PLOT 2` has visibility false, and `PLOT 1` has visibility true, which is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This code is running in macOS 13.0 app in Xcode 14.2 Swift 5

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    class Plot : Equatable {
        static func == (lhs: ContentView.Plot, rhs: ContentView.Plot) -> Bool {
            lhs === rhs
        }
        
        internal init(index: Int, visible: Bool = true) {
            self.index = index
            self.visible = visible
        }
        
        let index : Int
        var visible : Bool = true
    }
    
    struct PlotView : View {
        
        let plot : Plot
        
        struct Delegate {
            let moveDown : ()->Void
            let canMoveDown : ()->Bool
        }
        
        let delegate : Delegate
        
        @State private var visible = false
        
        var body : some View {
            HStack {
                Text("PLOT \(plot.index)")
                
                Button(action: {
                    visible.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "eye.circle" + (visible ? ".fill" : ""))
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    delegate.moveDown()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle")
                })
                .disabled(!delegate.canMoveDown())
            }
            .onAppear {
                visible = plot.visible
            }
            .onChange(of: visible) { v in
                plot.visible = v
                print("changed plot[\(plot.index)].visible = \(plot.visible ? "true" : "false")")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @State private var plots : [Plot] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(0..<plots.count, id: \.self) { i in
                PlotView.init(plot: plots[i], delegate: .init(moveDown: {
                    if i < plots.count-1 {
                        plots.swapAt(i, i+1)
                    } else {
                        plots.insert(plots.removeLast(), at: 0)
                    }
                }, canMoveDown: {
                    !plots.isEmpty
                }))
            }

            Button(action: {
                plots.append(.init(index: plots.count))
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say exactly why it doesn't work but it works with a `Plot` **struct** and `@Binding`

Don't nest the things, it's bad practice.

This is `Plot`, it became pretty tiny

```
struct Plot : Equatable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let index : Int
    var visible : Bool = true
}
```

Edit: In `ContentView` the `ForEach` expression iterates the element rather than the indices

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var plots : [Plot] = []
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ForEach($plots) { $plot  in
                    PlotView.init(plot: $plot, delegate: .init(moveDown: {
                        if let i = plots.firstIndex(of: plot),
                           i < plots.count-1 {
                            plots.swapAt(i, i+1)
                        } else {
                            plots.insert(plots.removeLast(), at: 0)
                        }
                    }, canMoveDown: {
                        !plots.isEmpty
                    }))
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    plots.append(.init(index: plots.count))
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `Plotview` the `Plot` instance is bound and the extra `visible` property as well as the `.onChange` modifier are not needed.

```
struct PlotView : View {
      
      @Binding var plot : Plot
      
      struct Delegate {
          let moveDown : ()->Void
          let canMoveDown : ()->Bool
      }
      
      let delegate : Delegate
      
      var body : some View {
          HStack {
              Text("PLOT \(plot.index)")
              
              Button(action: {
                  plot.visible.toggle()
              }, label: {
                  Image(systemName: "eye.circle" + (plot.visible ? ".fill" : ""))
              })
              
              Button(action: {
                  delegate.moveDown()
              }, label: {
                  Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle")
              })
              .disabled(!delegate.canMoveDown())
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I believe that `ForEach` orders its views based on an id, and in the case of a range 0..<count the iterator index becomes id; once it's set, unless the count changes, the views are identified by that id table.  If using `Identifiable` instead of a range it may work.  What did you mean by `Don't nest the things` -- nesting what things, and why is nesting bad practice?

Comment: Right, please see the edit. And nesting means to declare a class and a struct inside of another struct.